# Informatica - Concatenate Max value from each colum present in multiple rows for same Primary Key

Tags: etl, informatica, iics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtipC.jpg)

I have tried traditional approach of using Agg (Group By: ID, Store Name) and Max(Each Object) columns separately.

Then in next expression, Concat(Val1  Val2  Val3 || Val4).

How ever, I'm getting output as '0100'.

But, REQUIRED OUTPUT: 1100

Please let me know, how this can be done in IICS.

Answer (score 0):

IICS is similar to the Powercenter on-prem.

1. First use an aggregator.
   in `Group By` tab add ID, Store Name
   in `Aggregate` tab add max(object1)... please note to set data type and length correctly.
2. Then use an expression transformation.
   link ID, Store Name first.
   Then concat the max_* columns using pipe -
   out_max=max_col1||max_col2||... please note to set data type and length correctly.

This should generate correct output. I think you are having wrong output because of data length or data type of object fields. Make sure you trim spaces from object data before aggregator.